# Fix permission option removed from CWM recovery 6.0.3.6

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I updated to latest ClockWorkMode recovery in my **Galaxy S 3(AT&T,d2att)**.
**New version is 6.0.3.6.**
And noticed that Fix Permission option is removed from it.
I used that option when flasing ROMs.
I can't find why they did so. Will it affects flashing  new ROMs?   Is it not necessary?
Anyone knows reason behind that update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was removed because

> It's total placebo these days. I wrote it for dealing with the silly things that happen when we used to put apps on SD before Android supported it. Since then, it's been something of a sugar pill that magically fixes all problems without actually doing anything.

(Taken from the [commit history](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/45559/), posted by Steve Kondik)

Comment: So that's it.
It always did nothing. But Koushik Dutta keeps that option in ROM Manager.

Comment: That's probably an oversight, I don't think he's updated it recently but I expect it'll disappear from there soon too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [post from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2398339), fix permissions was [removed](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_bootable_recovery/commit/8736cc11d9dc7f4921008a4a5744092103cdac11). I haven't seen any reason why. However, somebody made a [flashable zip](http://db.tt/9aWdF8Rp) to put it back in.